# How to use COUNT with multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, count

How to use multiple columns with a single COUNT?

Assume that there is a table `demo` with these data:

```
id |  col1  |  col2  |    
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*  
1  |'alice' | 'book1'|  
2  |'bob'   | 'book1'|  
3  |'alice' | 'book2'|  
4  |'alice' | 'book3'|
```

I want to find the count of all the combination of user and book name.

I have tried that if i run with `distinct`, everything is alright.
`select count(distinct col1, col2) from demo`

However, when i remove `distinct`, then the sql statement will not be passed in mysql console.
`select count(col1, col2) from demo`

Question is how to use `COUNT` with multiple columns in MySql?

Answer (score 17):

There are several things you can count with `COUNT()` function:

- `count(*)` : rows
- `count(col1)` : rows where `col1` is not null
- `count(col2)` : rows where `col2` is not null
- `count(distinct col1)` : distinct `col1` values.
- `count(distinct col2)` : distinct `col2` values.
- `count(distinct col1, col2)` : distinct `(col1, col2)` values combinations.

Tested at **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45607/7)**:

```
    select 
        count(*)             as count_rows,
        count(col1)          as count_1,
        count(col2)          as count_2,
        count(distinct col1) as count_distinct_1,
        count(distinct col2) as count_distinct_2,
        count(distinct col1, col2) as count_distinct_1_2
    from demo ;
```

But `count(col1, col2)` is not valid syntax:

```
select 
    count(col1, col2) 
from demo ;
```

gives an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **`'col2) from demo'`** at line 2.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with multiple columns counts unique combinations of the specified columns' values. However, one other important point is that a tuple is counted only if *none* of the individual values in the tuple is null. If that last aspect of the behaviour is what you are trying to achieve, you could emulate it using a conditional inside `COUNT`. It could be either the standard-compliant `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM
  demo
;
```

or the MySQL-specific `IF` function:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(IF(col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL))
FROM
  demo
;
```

where instead of the `1` you can put any non-null constant. A row will be counted only if neither `col1` nor `col2` is null.

The obvious flaw of this workaround (either variation) is that it is clearly rather unwieldy and will become ridiculously long very quickly as you add more columns to account for.

It is possible to shorten the expression somewhat by choosing a less clear syntax. In particular, you could replace the `COUNT` with `SUM` and treat the predicates as numbers (1/0) in an arithmetic expression:

```
SELECT
  SUM( (col1 IS NOT NULL) * (col2 IS NOT NULL) )
FROM
  demo
;
```

In the context of the arithmetic operator `*` the logical result of the `IS NOT NULL` operator is implicitly converted to a number, 1 for True, 0 for False. With only 1s and 0s the `*` operator works as an equivalent of the logical `AND`: the final result will be 1 (True) only if *each* operand is 1; otherwise the result will be 0 (False). Adding up (`SUM`) the 1s is equivalent to counting the truths.

So again, the above statement will count only the rows where neither `col1` nor `col2` is null.

Comment: `SUM(col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL)` should work too, right?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Logically speaking, yes, it should.

Comment: que: What does `and` actual do inside a `count(col1 and col2)` -- what the `count()` is really counting at? Is there any documentation on it?

Comment: @Nor.Z > COUNT(Expression) is where the expression is non-null only. \
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354060/mysql-count-and-nulls \
So, the `and` is not doing anything special, `group by` is (still) needed.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the original question and example. Replace the comma with and.

[image: Class work that lead me to this question.]

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to **count the number of `(col1, col2)`** (-- both col as a single integral unit)

- Then maybe **use `group by`** is better.

  eg:

  ```sql
  select col1, col2, count(*) from demo
  group by col1, col2;
  ```
- Or **use `PARTITION BY`**

  eg:

  ```sql
  select *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) as countn from demo;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (select distinct col1, col2 from demo) as distinctAll
```

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. As explained by the OP and confirmed by ypercube's answer, `COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2)` already works fine in MySQL, you don't need to work around it by introducing a nested `SELECT DISTINCT`. What the OP is (or was) having problem with is how to do just `COUNT(col1, col2)` (*without* the `DISTINCT`). Or maybe there's more to what you are suggesting here? Could you perhaps edit your answer with an explanation? (Please note also that `COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2)` is *not* the same as `select count(*) from (select distinct col1, col2 from demo) as distinctAll`.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the fastest results, use a `UNION()`:

```
(
    SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS Table1Count,
    "-" AS Table2Count
    FROM TABLE1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
    "-" AS Table1Count,
    COUNT(id) AS Table2Count
    FROM TABLE2
)
```

Actual results:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Table1Count| Table2Count |
+------------+-------------+
| 11074      | -           |
| -          | 1           |
+------------+-------------+
```